# How can I display store currency instead of base currency in multiple website installation in Magento transactional emails?

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, multicurrency

I have a multiple website set up (USD and NRP, NPR being Nepalese Rupees).My client wants to display the store currency in  Grand Total instead of Base currency.The current display is as follows:

[image]

How can I achieve this in the simplest way possible? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Magento default just allows showing base currency when checking out. To display store view currency, you need to set up base currency for each store view. I think this extension is useful: because it allows setting up base currency for each store view easily: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-store-view-pricing.html

Comment: Did you solve the issue? @freerunner

Comment: Hii did you got the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Go to system => configuration.
At the top left, you can select the corresponding website. Please select website, change the base currency to your desired one and save. 
please note: You can change base currency only in website scope, not in store view scope.

Comment: Sorry, may be I could not make myself clear. I know how to change the currency settings and the currency scope. My base currency is USD. But, when I make purchase from NPR store, the "Grand total to be charged" (please refer to the snapshot in my question) displays in USD where as its supposed to be NPR(since the purchase is made from NPR store).

Answer (score 1):

If its in case of payment page use

```
Mage::helper('core')->currency($total, true, false);
```

or

```
$this->getOrder()->formatBasePrice($total);
```

else use this link maybe helpful for any one in need

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-convert-price-from-current-currency-to-base-currency-and-vice-versa/